# Use a graphing calculator to determine the following for the polynomial function $f(x)=x^4-4x^3-2x^2+5x+9$

Tags: calculus

Use ya graphing calculator to determine the following for the polynomial  function $f(x)=x^4-4x^3-2x^2+5x+9$

My Answers...

http://postimg.org/image/e0hrqf7az/
a) Domain 
b) Rnage
c) The Zeros
d) Y-Intercept
e) cordinates of realtive maximum
f) cordinates of realtive minmum
g) intervals where f(x)great then or equal to 0 
h) interveals where f(x) is smaller than 0

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of work for one "question"! Here's a quick refresher for each:

a) At this level, I'd say you have **domain** equal to "all real numbers", unless you have one or more of the following: [square root of negative number, division by zero, log of non-positive number]

b) To find the **range** using a graphing calculator, notice that since $f$ is of even degree, with positive leading coefficient, there will be a minimum. So the answer is not "all real numbers". If the polynomial were of odd degree, then the range *would be* "all real numbers". So this one is wrong. You'll have something of the form $[min, \infty)$

c) Use the "calculate zeros" function, or just have W|A do it...

d) The y-intercept is $f(0)$

e-f) omitted

g-h) Using the roots/zeros found in (c), you'll break the x-axis into intervals. $f$ is $\geq 0$ where the graph is (at or) above the x-axis. It's negative where the graph is below. Your answers will be intervals.

Comment: you are wrong mate.

Comment: @user73122: Please show me my errors. Which letter(s) are wrong?

Comment: Domain : Is all real numbers

Comment: and you missed the intervals where f(x)>0 etc. what are those

Comment: Yes. As I said, the default (at this level) is "all real numbers", **unless** you have one of those conditions. No conditions met --> Domain = all real numbers.

Comment: I did not "miss" those intervals. Are you the original poster? Why not log in with that account? Anywho... I have given a *method* for finding the intervals in (g-h).

Comment: for e) and f) you get the first derivative and look for sign changes. Where $f'(x)$ goes from negative to positive it's a relative minimum and the opposite is a maximum.

Comment: @Brian: Certainly that's the way to do it *without* a calculator. I'm catering the answer to those with a calculator, since the OP specifically mentions it.

Comment: @Chaz: I meant to graph the derivative and look at where it crosses the axis. That's the easiest thing I can think of.

Comment: @Brian: Indeed. But if $f'(x)$ has irrational roots, then we're back to the calculator!